# Given a space group, how to determine which layer groups are its subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am studying various crystals and the two-dimensional materials that could be potentially obtained by cleaving them (isolating a region bounded by two parallel planes).  In elucidating the properties of these materials, it would be good to know what symmetries could the cleaved material possess given the symmetry of the original crystal.  What is the best way to approach this problem?

My question can be alternatively interpreted as follows: how to find all the layer subgroups of all the space groups?  ("Look them up" is a legitimate answer for my purposes, if you can tell me where to look!)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group  and          http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_groups and     http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/    probably         http://www.cryst.ehu.es/